# Good area in Hong Kong for buying Electronics Accessories?

Tags: electronic-items, shopping, hong-kong

I'm currently on the bus to Heathrow, on my way to Hong Kong, and when I went to plug my laptop in I discovered I'd rather carelessly left my laptop power adapter at home! It's too late to go back and get it now, so tomorrow I'm going to need to go and buy one.

Is there a good mall / tower / few streets in Hong Kong for buying electronics accessories like power adapters, cables etc? (I've probably managed to forget something else too...) Ideally I'd like somewhere not too far from the centre, with a range of sellers nearby, so I'll both stand a good chance of getting what I need, and getting a good price. Is there such a place/area in Hong Kong?

Comment: Visit Sham Shui Po regardless !!! :-) - not very long by MTR and an utterly amazing area.

Comment: The Apliu Street Flea Market at Sham Shui Po was a lot more chaotic, but much more varied than the computer centres! I think it would've had the laptop adapter if I hadn't already bought one yesterday, but handily it did have various other adapters I either needed or quite fancied... Good tip, it was worth the visit :)

Comment: If you use Mac, there is Apple Store in IFC mall, where you can just walk from the Hong Kong station.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add to Josh B's answer -

- Wan Chai Computer Centre. Wan Chai MTR Station, Exit A4 on to the pedestrian bridge, there will be escalators when you hit the main road to let you get down to street level. It is right next to a McDonalds (you can see that sign from the bridge). Less busy than the rest, good range.
- Mong *Kok* Computer Centre. Mong Kok MTR Station [(not Mong Kok East), exit E2 (Bank Centre), walk straight across Sai Yeung Choi Street, then the next one and it will be on your right. There's usually a newspaper/magazine stand in front. That area is busy during all the waking hours though, especially on the weekends (mosh pit style crowds, minus the moshing of course), so you may want to try on a weekday. Hours are roughly 10-11am ish, until 6-7pm.
- Sham Shui Po Golden Computer Centre. Sham Shui Po MTR Station, follow the signs in the station. This one is a bit more out of the way and less touristy. Golden Computer Centre has two levels; the ground floor sells mostly games, consoles and accessories; the basement sells mainly computer accessories (keyboards, mice, cables, adapters, phone chargers etc.). There's also the Apliu Street markets, which sell all things electronic, like LED lights, torches, 2nd hand phones, power adapters, batteries.

Finally, there's your standard electrical chains in most shopping centres and strips which should also have what you want, probably a bit more expensive though. The main ones are Fortress and Broadway. If in doubt, you can always try Mong Kok, Sai Yeung Choi Street (Mong Kok Station, Exit E2) - these stores have practically every second shopfront on that strip. That's also a big tourist area, so the language barrier may be a bit easier.

One last thing - all the best to you for remembering which place has what at what price. There's nothing dodgy going on (well, not that I found), but it is a crazy mind game trying to remember where each store is, especially when they all pretty much look the same, and the centres aren't exactly laid out in the most logical manner.

Comment: The Wan Chai Computer Centre had exactly what I needed, and was open on a Sunday! Also thanks for the directions, very helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Where will you be...? If you are on Hong Kong island then [Wan Chai Computer Center](http://hong-kong-travel.org/Wan-Chai-Computer-Centre/) is great. On the Kowloon side there is Mong Gok Computer Center but I have never been there. Both will have power adapters. The Computer Centers can be intimidating to non-technical people but I always found the people in WCCC helpful and honest.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to pick one up at the airport or if you jump a train to the IFC mall it would be strange if you couldnt find one quickly inside there.

I'm a Mac person so I usually visit the Apple store in the IFC mall (Hong Kong MTR). In fact sometimes when I need to buy a new laptop I actually look for stopover flights in hong kong when I can jump on the MTR to Hong Kong from the airport, buy stuff and jump back on the train to the airport.

You can get All apple products for about 40% cheaper than in Europe and if it's from the Apple Store it has world wide warranty so you can return or replace in any Apple store.

Otherwise I'd say Wan Chai, Central/HK, and the shore side on Kowloon are best.

As mentioned, do try to go to a store which will give global warranty as this way you get the best price and the best security for your purchase.